# PHP 5.3 Notice: Undefined index in HTML Select

Tags: php, html, select, post

The code below generates under php 5.3 an **Notice: Undefined index: waehrungbep**. 
With `error_reporting(^^E_NOTICE)` i suppressed the message.
BUT How can  i fix the code rather than suppress the Notice?

```
<label for="WährungBEP" class="label"></label>
<select name="waehrungbep" id="waehrungbep" title="Waehrung w&auml;hlen." onChange="return recalc()">
 <option value="1.22" <?php if($_POST['waehrungbep'] == "1.22") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; }; ?>selected >EUR</option>
 <option value="1" <?php if($_POST['waehrungbep'] == "1") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; }; ?>>CHF</option>
 <option value="0.95" <?php if($_POST['waehrungbep'] == "0.95") { echo "selected=\"selected\""; }; ?>>$</option>
</select>
```

Comment: just a tip: for development always use `error_reporting(E_ALL)` - with older PHP versions `E_ALL | E_NOTICE` - this will save you a lot of mental illness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
<?php
    $waehrungbep = ( isset($_POST['waehrungbep']) ) ? $_POST['waehrungbep'] : false;
    function isSelected($var, $val, $default=false){
        $select = ($var == $val || ($default && $var === false) )  ? "selected=\"selected\"" : '';
        echo $select;
    }
?>
<label for="WährungBEP" class="label"></label>
<select name="waehrungbep" id="waehrungbep" title="Waehrung w&auml;hlen." onChange="return recalc()">
    <option value="1.22" <?php isSelected($waehrungbep, 1.22, true); ?>>EUR
    </option>
    <option value="1" <?php isSelected($waehrungbep, 1); ?>>CHF
    </option>
    <option value="0.95" <?php isSelected($waehrungbep, 0.95); ?>>$
    </option>
</select>
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/esk-fz7

keep in mind, that ternarys ar faster then if-statements.
You also use selected attribute and selected="selected" attributes, what means you are mixing up strict and not strict html.

Comment: Ups! The function isSelected allways returns -> "selected"! No mather wether the caller set's true or false.

Comment: i must say that i doubt that ternary is always fast than standard if constructs. Even if they are faster, the standard PHP application isn't an application where nanoseconds count (microseconds if you iterate thousands of times through a loop)

Answer (score 3):

change

```
if($_POST['waehrungbep'] == "1.22")
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['waehrungbep']) && $_POST['waehrungbep'] == "1.22")
```

Comment: Tested both solutions. Both are perfect. Many thanks to both of you, abimelex and nauphal.